# Yii - How to upload a csv to save in database?

Tags: php, csv, yii, fgetcsv

i'm with some troubles figuring out how to read the CSV file that I upload, probably i'm missing something in my Controller code.

```
  public function actionImport() {
    $model = new Produtos;
    $this->render('import', array('model' => $model) );

    if( isset($_FILES['csv_file']) ) {

      $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

      if ($handle) {
        while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) != FALSE) {
            $model->codigo          = $line[0];
            $model->nome            = $line[1];
            $model->descricao       = $line[2];
            $model->stock           = $line[3];
            $model->data_reposicao  = $line[4];

            $model->save();
        }        
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }

  }
```

This is only saving me the last line in the CSV... please some help!

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: make var_dump($_FILES) and you will find that you are passing an array. you need to pass a string

Comment: $_FILES['csv_file'][0]? Also make sure you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form

Comment: @SandeepBansal I changed to $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'] ... but still no luck in saving data... what you said didn't work

Comment: I've done some changes to the code, but it only saves the last line in the database... I'm out of ideas, can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to check whether your data is successfully validated or not.

Insert this code between yours:

```
        $model->data_reposicao  = $line[4];

        if (!$model->validate())
            throw new Exception("Validation failed.");

        $model->save();
```

So you can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think You missed the name of file, try $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for reference.
Also Yii does provide file handling, check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile for reference

Comment: thanks for the references! I'm still having some issues with csv.

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES is an array, which contains ['element_name']-array. In your case $_FILES is an array of $_FILES['csv_file']['name'], $_FILES['csv_file']['type'], $_FILES['csv_file']['error'], $_FILES['csv_file']['size'] and $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'].

So for short; $_FILES['csv_file'] is an array.

Comment: thanks, but now I have another problem, it is only saving me the last line in the CSV

Answer (score 1):

you are saving the same model instance again and again... that is why only the last line gets saved... you will have to create a new model for every line, i.e. in your while loop, add         `$model = new Produtos;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your model object every time when you need to insert your row into table. The code should be like:

```
public function actionImport() {
    $model = new Produtos;
    $this->render('import', array('model' => $model) );

    if( isset($_FILES['csv_file']) ) {

      $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

      if ($handle) {
        while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) != FALSE) {
            $modeln = new Produtos;
            $modeln->codigo          = $line[0];
            $modeln->nome            = $line[1];
            $modeln->descricao       = $line[2];
            $modeln->stock           = $line[3];
            $modeln->data_reposicao  = $line[4];

            $modeln->save();
        }        
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across this and just wanted to help someone who might be having the same issue (b/w issue is not with CSV or file upload)

Issue is with how Yii handles saving

You need to set isNewRecord attribute to true and primary key to NULL of model object before saving to save a new record everytime.

```
$model->PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN = NULL; //Replace PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN with the name of column
$model->isNewRecord = true;
$model->save();
```

You need to do above step whenever you are saving rows in loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['Userimportcsv']['tmp_name']['csv_file'], 'r');
if($handle) {                        
    $row = 1;
    while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) != FALSE) {
        if($row>1) {    
          $newModel = new Countries;
          $newModel->countryName       = $line[0];
          $newModel->status            = $line[1];
          $newModel->save();
        } 
        $row++;                     
    }                       
}
fclose($handle);
```